# Check dynamic object properties by dynamic expression

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I have a dynamically created object (ExpandoObject). I need to check if this object will be "drawn" or not by its properties.

The check is an expression which will also be created at runtime.
This expression contains clauses, different operators and is combined with "AND" and "OR".

Sometimes the expression checks for properties that doesn't exist on the object. For this reason, I thought it would be a good idea to have a dictionary with the property name as key. The expression will then also check for the existance of the key.

Sample 1: PropertyX == "a" || PropertyY == "b"

```
 {l => (IIF(l.ContainsKey("PropertyX"), l.Item["PropertyX"] == "a"), False) OR Invoke(l => IIF(l.ContainsKey("PropertyY"), l.Item["PropertyY"] == "b")), False), l))}
```

Sample 2: PropertyX == "a" && PropertyY == "b"

```
 {l => (IIF(l.ContainsKey("PropertyX"), l.Item["PropertyX"] == "a"), False) AndAlso Invoke(l => IIF(l.ContainsKey("PropertyY"), l.Item["PropertyY"] == "b")), False), l))}
```

My idea to check the object for validity was this:

```
var o = new ExpandoObject();
o.Add("PropertyX", "a");
o.Add("PropertyY", "b");
....
var items = o as IDictionary<string, object>;
var result = items.AsQueryable().Where(whereExpression);

bool isMatch = result.Any();
```

The problem:
If the expression contains only "OR" (Sample 1), it works fine and result.Any() can be used to tell if the object is drawn or not. But because I apply the where expression on a collection, the result for an expression with "AND" (Sample 2) will be an empty list and result.Any always returns false.

I feel like I'm in a dead end street now... My expression works fine, the items are filtered out correctly... But I cannot say if the object itself in general pass or not because I am checking against a collection.

Or is there another way to determine an objects properties for validity by an expression?

I hope you understand my problem :-)

Comment: In the [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) library there is a `PredicateBuilder` that lets you combine expressions. I wrote a variant of it (that doesn't require the AsExpandable()) here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29080249/613130

Comment: It's not clear why you're using LINQ for this at all. Why not just use `items` directly? (It's also not clear why you need `IQueryable` for this... just call `.Compile` on the expression tree to get a delegate, and apply that directly.)

Comment: @JonSkeet My knowledge about expressions is very limited, I don't know how to apply it directly. This is why I ended up with a collection... which doesn't work. Can you show me how to apply the delegate on items?

Comment: Well assuming you've got a `Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool>` you'd just use `if (func(items))`. Note that your expression needs to use string equality though, as the value in the dictionary is statically typed as `object`, not `string`...

Comment: Thanks Jon! My mistake was not applying the expression directly like you said. Now everything is working! :-)